# How to modify a Slider to get double values?

Tags: java, user-interface, slider, double

I want to make a slider which is between 0 and 1.0. I set it's major and minor tick spacing to double values but it displays an error that I can not use it like that.

```
JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 1, 15);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(0.2);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(0.1);
```

How can I modify a slider in order to give double values into it? Any tips would be helpful.

Comment: "but it displays an error that I can not use it like that" - What made you not post the *error*?

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that you are stuck with INT. However you can "trick" it by multyplying the values by 10.

```
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 1, 15);
    Hashtable labelTable = new Hashtable();
    labelTable.put( 0, new JLabel("0.0") );
    labelTable.put( 1, new JLabel("0.1") );
    labelTable.put(2, new JLabel("0.2") );
    labelTable.put(10, new JLabel("1.0") );
    slider.setLabelTable(labelTable);
```

Comment: Don’t forget the code that sets the major and minor tick spacing.